# How to access to an element that is on an object inside another object?

Tags: javascript

Here is the "big" array that contains two objects here:

```
bigArray : [Object, Object]
          0:Object
            id:"1"
            text:"t1"
          1:Object
            id:"2"
            text:"t2"
```

This what `console.log(bigArray)` returns.

My question is: How to get the two elements t1 and t2 to verify if one of them is undefined (one of them or both)?

Comment: `typeof bigArray[0] == 'undefined' || typeof bigArray[1] == 'undefined'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
bigArray.some(x=> typeof x === "undefined")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array which you are getting and check for the field in the following manner:

```
var bigArray = [
          {

            id:"1",
            text:"t1"
          },
          {
            id:"2",
            text:"t2"
          }
         ];

            for ( var i = 0; i< bigArray.length; i++ ) {
                alert(bigArray[i].id);
              // this field will be the field agains which you need to check
              if ( typeof bigArray[i].somefield == "undefined" ) {
                alert("its undefined");
              }
            }
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/sjmd06rm/1/